# optimise query with two ILIKEs in different tables

Tags: postgresql

I am analyzing the query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from filings
left join filing_types as ft on filing_type_id = ft.id
left join filing_type_categories as ftc on ftc.filing_type_id = ft.id
left join filing_categories as fc on ftc.filing_category_id = fc.id
where filings.sources_id in (11,4,9,6,10)
    and (ft.name::text ilike '\''%sec%'\''
            or fc.name::text ilike '\''%sec%'\'')
limit 10
```

it's too slow:

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1.14..1101.12 rows=10 width=788) (actual time=147315.431..188299.498 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=48242 read=1345818
   ->  Merge Right Join  (cost=1.14..100773826.35 rows=916136 width=788) (actual time=147315.430..188299.496 rows=10 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: (ft.id = filings.filing_type_id)
         Filter: ((ft.name ~~* '%sec%'::text) OR (fc.name ~~* '%sec%'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 1696576
         Buffers: shared hit=48242 read=1345818
         ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.57..62453.32 rows=54818 width=81) (actual time=0.062..59.882 rows=349 loops=1)
               Merge Cond: (ft.id = ftc.filing_type_id)
               Buffers: shared hit=127 read=118
               ->  Index Scan using filing_types_pk on filing_types ft  (cost=0.29..35381.07 rows=54818 width=42) (actual time=0.008..20.056 rows=308 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=61 read=47
               ->  Materialize  (cost=0.28..26897.11 rows=3048 width=39) (actual time=0.049..39.227 rows=150 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=66 read=71
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.28..26889.49 rows=3048 width=39) (actual time=0.044..39.015 rows=150 loops=1)
                           Join Filter: (ftc.filing_category_id = fc.id)
                           Rows Removed by Join Filter: 33694
                           Buffers: shared hit=66 read=71
                           ->  Index Scan using filing_type_categories_id_unique_idx on filing_type_categories ftc  (cost=0.28..7129.57 rows=3048 width=12) (actual time=0.011..32.205 rows=150 loops=1)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=65 read=69
                           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..9.50 rows=433 width=27) (actual time=0.001..0.021 rows=226 loops=150)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
                                 ->  Seq Scan on filing_categories fc  (cost=0.00..7.33 rows=433 width=27) (actual time=0.016..0.647 rows=430 loops=1)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
         ->  Index Scan using filings_filing_type_id_index on filings  (cost=0.56..100214194.16 rows=28567959 width=707) (actual time=3.603..185447.980 rows=1696586 loops=1)
               Filter: (sources_id = ANY ('{11,4,9,6,10}'::integer[]))
               Buffers: shared hit=48115 read=1345700
 Planning time: 5.559 ms
 Execution time: 188299.709 ms
(29 rows)
```

And I don't even use `order by` here which will make it even slower.
Although if I use ILIKE separately in two different queries it gives decent results:

### 1

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from filings
left join filing_types as ft on filing_type_id = ft.id
left join filing_type_categories as ftc on ftc.filing_type_id = ft.id
left join filing_categories as fc on ftc.filing_category_id = fc.id
where filings.sources_id in (11,4,9,6,10)
    and (ft.name::text ilike '\''%sec%'\'')
limit 10'
                                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=565.95..678.30 rows=10 width=788) (actual time=432.073..2774.232 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1485 read=75800
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=565.95..9719780.91 rows=865126 width=788) (actual time=432.071..2774.227 rows=10 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=1485 read=75800
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=565.68..6589539.61 rows=865126 width=761) (actual time=432.059..2773.593 rows=10 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=1468 read=75799
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=565.40..2392164.15 rows=865126 width=749) (actual time=432.038..2771.141 rows=8 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (filings.filing_type_id = ft.id)
                     Buffers: shared hit=1449 read=75796
                     ->  Seq Scan on filings  (cost=0.00..2030932.89 rows=28567959 width=707) (actual time=0.530..2507.472 rows=1821105 loops=1)
                           Filter: (sources_id = ANY ('{11,4,9,6,10}'::integer[]))
                           Buffers: shared hit=1440 read=75367
                     ->  Hash  (cost=544.64..544.64 rows=1661 width=42) (actual time=57.801..57.801 rows=1043 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 100kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=6 read=429
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on filing_types ft  (cost=24.87..544.64 rows=1661 width=42) (actual time=1.395..57.105 rows=1043 loops=1)
                                 Recheck Cond: (name ~~* '%sec%'::text)
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=432
                                 Buffers: shared hit=6 read=429
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on filing_types_name_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..24.46 rows=1661 width=0) (actual time=0.913..0.913 rows=1043 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: (name ~~* '%sec%'::text)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
               ->  Index Scan using filing_type_categories_id_unique_idx on filing_type_categories ftc  (cost=0.28..4.84 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.243..0.299 rows=1 loops=8)
                     Index Cond: (filing_type_id = ft.id)
                     Buffers: shared hit=19 read=3
         ->  Index Scan using filing_categories_pk on filing_categories fc  (cost=0.27..3.63 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.060..0.060 rows=1 loops=10)
               Index Cond: (ftc.filing_category_id = id)
               Buffers: shared hit=17 read=1
 Planning time: 89.261 ms
 Execution time: 2774.694 ms
(30 rows)
```

### 2

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from filings
left join filing_types as ft on filing_type_id = ft.id
left join filing_type_categories as ftc on ftc.filing_type_id = ft.id
left join filing_categories as fc on ftc.filing_category_id = fc.id
where filings.sources_id in (11,4,9,6,10)
    and (fc.name::text ilike '\''%sec%'\'')
limit 10'
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1001.96..3212.19 rows=10 width=788) (actual time=0.115..0.115 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=3
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1001.96..811271.22 rows=3666 width=788) (actual time=0.115..0.115 rows=0 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=3
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..131.79 rows=7 width=81) (actual time=0.115..0.115 rows=0 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=3
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..93.99 rows=7 width=39) (actual time=0.115..0.115 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: (ftc.filing_category_id = fc.id)
                     Buffers: shared hit=3
                     ->  Seq Scan on filing_categories fc  (cost=0.00..8.41 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.113..0.113 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Filter: (name ~~* '%sec%'::text)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 433
                           Buffers: shared hit=3
                     ->  Seq Scan on filing_type_categories ftc  (cost=0.00..47.48 rows=3048 width=12) (never executed)
               ->  Index Scan using filing_types_pk on filing_types ft  (cost=0.29..5.40 rows=1 width=42) (never executed)
                     Index Cond: (id = ftc.filing_type_id)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on filings  (cost=1001.67..115396.39 rows=48067 width=707) (never executed)
               Recheck Cond: ((filing_type_id = ft.id) AND (sources_id = ANY ('{11,4,9,6,10}'::integer[])))
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on filings_filing_type_id_sources_id_action_date_idx  (cost=0.00..989.66 rows=48067 width=0) (never executed)
                     Index Cond: ((filing_type_id = ft.id) AND (sources_id = ANY ('{11,4,9,6,10}'::integer[])))
 Planning time: 8.653 ms
 Execution time: 0.273 ms
(22 rows)
```

But I need to search through both tables

Indices:

```
# \d filing_types
                              Table "public.filing_types"
   Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                  
------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 id         | integer |           | not null | nextval('filing_types_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | text    |           | not null | 
 sources_id | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "filing_types_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "name_unique_idx" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
    "filing_types_name_gin_trgm_idx" gin (name gin_trgm_ops)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "filing_types_sources_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (sources_id) REFERENCES sources(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "filing_type_categories" CONSTRAINT "filing_type_categories_filing_types" FOREIGN KEY (filing_type_id) REFERENCES filing_types(id)



# \d filing_type_categories
                                  Table "public.filing_type_categories"
       Column       |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                       
--------------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer |           | not null | nextval('filing_type_categories_id_seq'::regclass)
 filing_category_id | integer |           | not null | 
 filing_type_id     | integer |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "filing_type_categories_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "filing_type_categories_id_unique_idx" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (filing_type_id, filing_category_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "filing_type_categories_filing_categories" FOREIGN KEY (filing_category_id) REFERENCES filing_categories(id)
    "filing_type_categories_filing_types" FOREIGN KEY (filing_type_id) REFERENCES filing_types(id)

# \d filing_categories
                              Table "public.filing_categories"
   Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                    
------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------
 id         | integer |           | not null | nextval('filing_categories_id_seq'::regclass)
 name       | text    |           |          | 
 sources_id | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "filing_categories_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "filing_categories_name_unique_idx" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
    "filing_categories_name_gin_trgm_idx" gin (name gin_trgm_ops)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "filing_categories_sources_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (sources_id) REFERENCES sources(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "filing_type_categories" CONSTRAINT "filing_type_categories_filing_categories" FOREIGN KEY (filing_category_id) REFERENCES filing_categories(id)
```

And `filings` table index for `sources_id` column:

```
"filings_sources_id_idx" btree (sources_id)
```

Postgres version:

```
# SELECT version();
                                                                              version                                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.0 on x86_64-apple-darwin, compiled by i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Comment: In global query, filings_filing_type_id_index index scan takes a lot of times with many I/O. In query 1, filings table scan is very fast with about 50% of I/O: are the the execution times reproducible - one may ask if OS file system cache influence query execution time ?

Comment: `OR` is a performance killer. Consider the `UNION` of two queries, each without an `OR`.

Comment: If you don't want to change the initial query, you could try to create a partial index to make the index scan faster with `create index on filings(sources_id) where filings.sources_id in (11,4,9,6,10);` - it should be faster for this query but sources_id values are hardcoded and you have an index just for one query.

Comment: Is it really necessary for all your joins to be left joins?

Comment: "And I don't even use order by here which will make it even slower."  If an ORDER BY is necessary, then optimizing the wrong query is likely to be a waste of time.

Comment: creating the index `create index on filings(sources_id) where filings.sources_id in (11,4,9,6,10);` and inner join helped a lot, thanx